# XML having field name and value in response to map java object unable to retrive from fields

Tags: java, xml, data-binding

I have below  response as xml I need to map to java object I tried with jaxb,sax,dom unable get the data from below  `<FIELD NAME="strShipmentNo" VALUE="A134535" />`  data. Please suggest how to retrieve the data from below xml

```
<DTDCREPLY>
    <CONSIGNMENT>
        <CNHEADER>
            <CNTRACK>TRUE</CNTRACK>
            <FIELD NAME="strShipmentNo" VALUE="A15082271" />
            <FIELD NAME="strRefNo" VALUE="N/A" />
            <FIELD NAME="strMode" VALUE="AIR" />
            <FIELD NAME="strOrigin" VALUE="LEAK-PROOF ENGINEERING PVT.LTD, AHMEDABAD" />
            <FIELD NAME="strOriginRemarks" VALUE="Received from" />
            <FIELD NAME="strBookedOn" VALUE="08072009" />
            <FIELD NAME="strPieces" VALUE="1" />
            <FIELD NAME="strWeightUnit" VALUE="Kg" />
            <FIELD NAME="strWeight" VALUE="0.020" />
            <FIELD NAME="strDestination" VALUE="PUNE" />
            <FIELD NAME="strStatus" VALUE="DELIVERY" />
            <FIELD NAME="strStatusTransOn" VALUE="09072009" />
            <FIELD NAME="strStatusTransTime" VALUE="1210" />
            <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE="CO SEAL" />
            <FIELD NAME="strNoOfAttempts" VALUE="" />
        </CNHEADER>
        <CNBODY>
            <CNACTIONTRACK>TRUE</CNACTIONTRACK>
            <CNACTION>
                <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="DISPATCHED" />
                <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE="" />
            </CNACTION>
            <CNACTION>
                <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="RECEIVED" />
                <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE="" />
            </CNACTION>
            <CNACTION>
                <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="DISPATCHED" />
                <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE="" />
            </CNACTION>
            <CNACTION>
                <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="RECEIVED" />
                <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE="" />
            </CNACTION>
            <CNACTION>
                <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="OUT FOR DELIVERY" />
                <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE="" />
            </CNACTION>
        </CNBODY>
    </CONSIGNMENT>
</DTDCREPLY>
```

Comment: This can be done in any of jaxb, sax, dom if you have valid xml (which yours isn't quite).  Please show us how you've tried in at least one of these and explain how it failed for you.

Comment: @Anshu - There was an end tag for `DTDCREPLY` but it wasn't indented the necessary 4 spaces so that it was visible.  I edited the question so that it appears correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using [XStream](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/08/18/xstream.html), you can serialize most Java objects without any mapping. Object names become element names in the XML produced, and the strings within classes form the element content of the XML. The classes that you serialize with XStream don't need to implement the Serializable interface. XStream is a serialization tool and not a data binding tool, which means that it doesn't perform class generation from an XML or XML Schema Definition (XSD) file. Check this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137655/design-paradigm-for-instantiating-object-from-xml-file/12636771#12636771)

Comment: Can XStream handle invalid XML?

Comment: I dont think so. Did he mention anything about invalid xml?

Comment: The shared XML doesn't look to be valid

Comment: FYI - Data binding solutions like JAXB (JSR-222) implementations don't require that the model be generated from an XML schema, or that the model contain any annotations:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below I'll demonstrate how you could you could map your use case using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)'s `@XmlPath` extension.

**CNBody**

```
package forum12934737;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="CNBODY")
public class CNBody {

    @XmlElement(name="CNACTIONTRACK")
    private String cnActionTrack;

    @XmlElement(name="CNACTION")
    private List<CNAction> cnActions;

}
```

**CNAction**

Using the `@XmlPath` extension we can specify that we want to map our field/property to an XML attribute nested within an XML element which has another XML attribute of a certain value.

```
package forum12934737;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CNAction {

    @XmlPath("FIELD[@NAME='strAction']/@VALUE")
    private String strAction;

    @XmlPath("FIELD[@NAME='strRemarks']/@VALUE")
    private String strRemarks;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum12934737;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CNBody.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum12934737/input.xml");
        CNBody cnBody = (CNBody) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(cnBody, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

For the purpose of this example I am using a subset of your XML document.

```
<CNBODY>
   <CNACTIONTRACK>TRUE</CNACTIONTRACK>
   <CNACTION>
      <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="DISPATCHED"/>
      <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE=""/>
   </CNACTION>
   <CNACTION>
      <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="RECEIVED"/>
      <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE=""/>
   </CNACTION>
   <CNACTION>
      <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="DISPATCHED"/>
      <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE=""/>
   </CNACTION>
   <CNACTION>
      <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="RECEIVED"/>
      <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE=""/>
   </CNACTION>
   <CNACTION>
      <FIELD NAME="strAction" VALUE="OUT FOR DELIVERY"/>
      <FIELD NAME="strRemarks" VALUE=""/>
   </CNACTION>
</CNBODY>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html